# Request.Browser.MajorVersion different on win2k3 from windows 7

Tags: asp.net

I'm using chrome which currently sends the following user-agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36`

On Windows server 2k3 the following expression

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MajorVersion
```

returns `5`

On my development machine, which runs windows 7, the MajorVersion returns `28`.

`5` is obviously very strange, `28` seems better, but I want to revert to the old behavior because I need to support this legacy project...

Is there a web.config param to provide a fallback to the old behavior??